# Why is created Bitmap bigger than decoded Bitmap from Resources in Android?

Tags: android, resources, bitmap

I don't understand why is Bitmap created with `Bitmap.createBitmap()` bigger (more kB in native heap), than decoded Bitmap with `BitmapFactory.decodeResource()`.

I'm working with LG Optimus One (dpi is 160, Android 2.2) and I'm measuring allocated memory with `Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize()`.

If I created Bitmap (200x200) by this way:

```
Bitmap createdBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Then the size of native heap increased by c. **160kB**.

But if I decoded PNG image (200x200) from resource (from folder `drawable-mdpi`):

```
Bitmap mdpiBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_mdpi);
```

The size increased by c. **only 3kB**.

But if I decode PNG image (150x150) from `drawable-ldpi`, then Android scale up the image to 200x200 and the size of native heap increase also by c. **160kB**.

**Does someone know, why is created Bitmap and decoded (scaled) Bitmap so big?**

Thanks for answer.

**Here is code I used to measure:**

```
long createdSizeStart = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
Bitmap createdBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(200, 200, Config.ARGB_8888);
long createdSize = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() - createdSizeStart;

long resourceMdpiSizeStart = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
Bitmap resourceMdpiBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_mdpi);
long resourceMdpiSize = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() - resourceMdpiSizeStart;

long resourceLdpiSizeStart = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize();
Bitmap resourceLdpiBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image_ldpi);
long resourceLdpiSize = Debug.getNativeHeapAllocatedSize() - resourceLdpiSizeStart;

Log.i("test", "Created: " + createdSize + " B, " + createdBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + createdBitmap.getHeight());
Log.i("test", "Resource MDPI: " + resourceMdpiSize + " B, " + resourceMdpiBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + resourceMdpiBitmap.getHeight());
Log.i("test", "Resource LDPI: " + resourceLdpiSize + " B, " + resourceLdpiBitmap.getWidth() + "x" + resourceLdpiBitmap.getHeight());
```

**The output is:**
Created: 163952 B, 200x200
Resource MDPI: 3184 B, 200x200
Resource LDPI: 164424 B, 200x200

Answer (score 3):

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled=false;
Bitmap bitmap;
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whatever, options);
```

Not too sure what your intents are... The code snippet above will create a Bitmap R.drawable.whatever at the actual size... no scaling... same dimensions as it was when you created the resource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helped me in a project I'm working on atm. Thank you! It was really helpful to fix an issue.

Answer (score 1):

> "Does someone know, why is created Bitmap and decoded (scaled) Bitmap so big?"

160KB seems correct for 200*200*4 bytes. Your question should be "why is the MDPI bitmap so small?".

I wonder if the MDPI version has been loaded previously by some other piece of code, and this data is being reused.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the size of the Bitmap is correct. And do you know a way to control preloading of resources? Because when I decode LDPI image on MDPI device, then there are two images in memory (the original preloaded image and the scaled up version). But the original image is never used (just for creating the scaled up version). So I'd like to remove the original image from memory and keep just the scaled up image.

Comment: I don't know how you'd control preloading. Are you running out of memory? Maybe it will be unloaded or GC'd automatically if memory gets low.

Comment: Yes, I was getting OOM exception for images in different DPI. I fixed it by loading images through stream and then drawing it into `Canvas` with specified `Rect`, so the image looks same. But I think it would be better to have it in correct width & height. So I'd like to release useless images.